# Replacing Unicode character / Python / Django

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

Since I'm pretty much forced to replace some unicode characters in my string returned by some OCR technology the only way I found to do it is replace them "one by one". This is done using following code:

```
def recode(mystr):
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u0104', '\u0104')
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u017c', '\u017c')
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u0106' , '\u0106')
    ...
    ...
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u017a' , '\u017a')
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u017c' , '\u017c')
    return mystr
```

I know this might be confusing. The string returned by mentioned OCR API is returning a sequence of characters, for example "\u017a" is not a mapped character in Unicode but rather `"\" , "u", "0", "1", "7", "a"`. But this can't be changed from my end.

The above solution is very messy and unprofessional. However if I try to loop through all the characters that I want to "replace" it seems like it doesn't do anything:

```
def recode(mystr):
    for foo in ['\u0106','\u0118','\u0141', ...... , '\u017a','\u017c']:
        mystr = mystr.replace(r'%s' % foo, foo)
    return mystr
```

Why in this case the `foo` string is not read as a raw text if in first scenario it is done properly? What is the difference?

Comment: Look at `str.translate` and `str.maketrans`...

Answer (score 0):

So the reason why `foo` is not read as raw text is that the `r` in front of a string only plays a role when the string is *created* - afterwards it will act as a normal string - for example when the `%`-operator is applied.

As a solution to what you want to do, you can try something like this:

```py
bar = r"\u0104"
mystr = mystr.replace(bar, chr(int(bar[2:], 16)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an X-Y problem.  The API is returning literal Unicode strings.  Maybe it is actually JSON and OP should be doing `json.loads()` on the returned data, but if not you can use the `unicode_escape` codec to translate the escape codes.  That codec requires a byte string so it may need to be encoded via `ascii` or `latin1` first:

```py
def recode(mystr):
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u0104', '\u0104')
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u017c', '\u017c')
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u0106' , '\u0106')
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u017a' , '\u017a')
    mystr = mystr.replace(r'\u017c' , '\u017c')
    return mystr

def recode2(s):
    return s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape')

s = r'\u0104\u017c\u0106\u017a\u017c'
print(s)
print(recode(s))
print(recode2(s))
```

Output:

```
\u0104\u017c\u0106\u017a\u017c
ĄżĆźż
ĄżĆźż
```